# Storing some value in variable while using lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am working with `java-8`. Please see the following code snippet -

```
studentsOfThisDept = students.stream()
                .filter(s -> (student != null
                        && s.getDepartment() != null
                        && s.getDepartment().getCode().equals("CS")
                        ))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here I have to perform 2 check -

```
s.getDepartment() != null ; // 1st check
```

and

```
s.getDepartment().getCode().equals("CS") // 2nd check
```

Is there any way that I can store the value of `s.getDepartment()` to some variable (say `dept`) so that in second check I can write -

```
dept.getCode().equals("CS");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Introduce a variable after filtering null students

```
studentsOfThisDept = students.stream()
            .filter(s -> s != null)
            .filter(s -> {
                     Dept dept = s.getDepartment();
                     return dept != null && dept.getCode().equals("CS");
                    })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`filter()` takes a predicate, which means the lambda block can do things like declare variables, log stuff etc. Just make sure to return a boolean at the end of the block. A predicate is a function that takes an object and returns boolean.

Comment: @Razib Yes. Because Predicate is a functional interface with an abstract method with the signature `boolean test(T t)`. This is the method you are implementing as a lambda. So in order to satisfy this interface, you have to return a boolean. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is

```
studentsOfThisDept = students.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(s -> Optional.ofNullable(s.getDepartment())
                         .map(Department::getCode).filter(c -> c.equals("CS")).isPresent()
           )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
studentsOfThisDept = students.stream()
            .filter(s -> {
                    if (s == null) return false;
                    Department dep = s.getDepartment();
                    return (dep != null && dep.getCode().equals("CS")
                    );})
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```